# How to test Exception handler with mockito without a real controller call (Spring)

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, controller, mockito

I have a Controller

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "something/{year}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public MyObject get(@PathVariable("year") int year throws MyException {
    return myService.get(year);
}
```

If the year is not correct, it's gonna throw an error and this error is caught by my ErrorInterceptor class

```java
@ExceptionHandler(value = {MyException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMyException(MyException ex, WebRequest request) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    ResponseEntity<Object> res = handleExceptionInternal(ex, ex.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = getMyResponse((ServletWebRequest) request, res);
    return response;
}
```

The method getMyResponse creates an object with customed error message (path, code error, etc.)
My question is how can I test it with Mockito without making a real call of the controller.
I've tested with MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller) .setControllerAdvice(myInterceptor).build() but it's always null (I don't want to make a real call).

I also tried adding Mockito.when and Mockity.verify to fake the call but I can't get retrieve the path and stuff...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if the interceptor is returning the correct response, you could create a class which is extenting the interceptor and provides an public wrapper method for `handleMyException`. Then you instantiate that new class, call the wrapper and assert on the returned response.